# Cláusula where demora muito

Tags: laravel, query, select, laravel-eloquent, where

Estou usando o Laravel 5.6

Minha model está normal

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class MyTable extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'myTable';
    public $timestamps = false;

}
```

Estou tentando fazer uma consulta simples onde é para trazer 8 registros

Estou usando assim:

```
 public function getDevice( Request $request  ){
        $ip = $request->input('ip');       
        $table = MyTable::where('description', $ip );
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($table );
        echo "</pre>";
        /*
        return response()->json($table);
        */
    }
```

Mas ele está travando e não está trazendo o resultado

Considere a tabela

```
id | description| status | 
1  |  1         |   0    |
2  |  1         |   1    |
3  |  1         |   0    |
4  |  1         |   1    |
```

Mas se eu usar assim

```
$query DB::select('SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE description = ?', [1]);
```

ou se trazer só um

```
$table = MyTable::find(1); 

$table = MyTable::all();
```

Funciona

Comment: já tentou usar aspas simples? `$query DB::select("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE description = '?'", 1);`

Comment: Desse jeito funciona, mas desse jeito `$table = MyTable::where('description', $ip );` não funciona

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Da forma que você está usando a query apenas está sendo armazenada, não executada. Caso queira realmente executar a query vc deve usar comandos como o find ou get. Tente trocar o seguinte código

`$table = MyTable::where('description', $ip );`

por esse

`$table = MyTable::where('description', $ip )->get();`

Comment: Carambaaa!! Realmente tinha me esquecido desse detalhe